# Overfull Heading when using Decimal Point Alignment in Table

Tags: tables, sectioning, decimal-number

I want decimal point alignment in my table (below). However this messes up the heading (overfull error), even though I have it across 2 lines. How can I overcome this problem? Thanks

```
\begin{table}[!t]
\caption{Specific Acid Added to Samples}
\label{Acid_Added}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}c  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=2.2] }
\hline
ID & Specific Acid & Spread & Specific Acid \\
& Weight [mg] & Weight [g] & Conc [mg/g] \\
\hline
1   &0.20   &19.96  &0.01\\
2   &0.40   &20.00  &0.02\\
3   &1.00   &19.98  &0.05\\
4   &2.00   &20.00  &0.10\\
5   &4.00   &20.00  &0.20\\
6   &10.00  &20.00  &0.50\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You should recieve error messages from that code. Do you? To get rid of them, add a pair of {} around everything in S type columns that is not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If turned into a complete MWE, your code results in a bunch of error messages like the following: `siunitx error: "invalid-number" Invalid numerical input 'e'.` They are caused by the column headers in the `S` type columns. Since they are text rather than numbers, they have to be enclosed in a set of `{}`. In the following MWE, I have also corrected the `table-format` option of the last column as well as used the `\si` command from `siunitx` to display the units. Lastly, I have also replaced the `\hline`s by horizontl lines from the `booktabs` package for a better vertical spacing around the lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abbreviations=true,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Specific Acid Added to Samples}
\label{Acid_Added}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}c  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=1.2] }
\toprule
ID & {Specific Acid} & {Spread} & {Specific Acid} \\
& {Weight [\si{\mg}]} & {Weight [\si{\g}]} & {Conc [\si{\mg\per\g}]} \\
\midrule
1   &0.20   &19.96  &0.01\\
2   &0.40   &20.00  &0.02\\
3   &1.00   &19.98  &0.05\\
4   &2.00   &20.00  &0.10\\
5   &4.00   &20.00  &0.20\\
6   &10.00  &20.00  &0.50\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @leandriis, that's incredibly helpful. What what be the best way of making "ID" vertically centered in the header? Also, are there any other suggestions or recommendations you would have to make this table more aesthetically pleasing? (the horizontal lines from the booktabs package look a lot better, so thank you for this suggestion)